# visual studio code does not show IntelliSense for VueJs

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3

i have a simple Vuejs projet that only have an index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="hello-vue" class="demo">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and app.js File

```
const HelloVueApp = {
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello VueXYZ!!'
      }
    }
  }
  
  Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#hello-vue')
```

The problem is that i dont have any IntelliSense  for the code in

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

when i hover the mouse over a method of the Vue Object  it only show (ANY)

Comment: I installed Vetur but it does not change anything

Comment: Did you follow the setup of Vetur? https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/setup.html#extensions

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but for those who still have the same problem;

Make sure you have installed [**Vue - Official**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) (prev. Volar) which is official Vue extension for VS Code.

If you are coding with TS you also need to install [**TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin).

Note that if you have install both and you code Js but not TS, then your extensions won't work. In that case you'll need to disable **TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)** extension only and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

***Download these two extensions***

Add these two extension in your vs code your problem will be solved

[image]